# wrapAll and andSelf not wrapping self element

Tags: javascript, jquery, wrapall

I'm using the code below:

```
$('.graph-img').each(function(index) {
    $(this).prev('h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p').prevUntil('.graph-img').andSelf().not('h1').wrapAll("<div class='prevent-break'>");
});
```

It's wrapping all the elements, but excluding `.graph-img` that this currently refers to. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`andSelf` doesn't add the **first** set of elements, but the **previous** one.

You may use `.add(this)` instead here.

Note that [andSelf](https://api.jquery.com/andself/) has been deprecated in favor of `addBack` whose name is less misleading.